# Filtering thousands of rows by comparing two columns

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to filter and copy a table of ~2500 rows and 15 columns. The criterion should be that the row value in column D is greater than that in column O.
Sounds simple enough but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I tried so far:

## Standard Filters

Obviously insufficient as they can only compare a column to a constant value.

## Advanced Filters

I added a column P in the same sheet with the formula `=O1 < D1` expanded from row 1 to the end, giving me nice results.
However, when selecting the columns, clicking advanced filter and specifying column P (`$Sheet1.$P$1:$P$2500`) as filter criteria source, I just get the following warnings:

> This range does not contain a valid query

So I assume a cannot simply have a criterion that says true/false but must directly write it as text into the cells. Here is where I am stuck.

I filled the first cell of that column with the formula but without `=` like `O1 < D1`. However, I need to expand it to all rows. When I do that "the normal way", I only get expansion on the second cell reference, so the third row entry says `O1 < D3`.
I am not inclined to fix every one of these thousands of occurrences of `O1` by hand.
How can I solve this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so focused on this "complex" problem that can "only be solved with advanced filtering" that I ruled out standard filters prematurely:

After having created the true/false filter column (with `=O1 < D1`), I can use the standard filter on this column. However, note that one disadvantage is, that this column will be carried on in the copying.